# jQuery fadeIn() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script but the fadein() part is not working. Not getting any errors though..

```
$('<ol/>', {
  'class': 'raw-list',
  html: items.join('')
 }).appendTo('.json').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to hide it first with the following code :

```
$('<ol/>', {
  'class': 'raw-list',
  html: items.join('')
})
.hide()
.fadeIn(1000)
.appendTo('.json');
```

Answer (score 7):

`fadeIn()` won't do anything if the element is already visible.

You need to `hide()`  it first.

Answer (score 0):

The trick =)

```
$('.hidden').fadeTo(300, 1);
```