# jquery fadeIn() instantly appears

Tags: jquery

First, this isn't a duplicate of [jQuery fadeIn 'slow' immediately appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888938/jquery-fadein-slow-immediately-appearing) or [jQuery fadeIn() doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814239/jquery-fadein-doesnt-work). I have tried what they suggested and it's not working.

I have tried this:

```
$('#tblClues tr:last').after(templateContents).fadeIn(3000);
```

...and I have tried this:

```
$('#tblClues tr:last').after(templateContents).hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

The appended html contents do not fade in -- it instantly appears. Help. (Not sure if it matters, but I'm stripping off  tags from templateContents because it was jacking up the rendered table.)

** EDIT **

Here is the full contents of `templateContents`:

```
<tr id="templateRow2_1" class="MaroonRow">
   <td colspan="2">
      <input type="text" id="txtStepTitle1">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="templateRow3_1">
   <td valign="top">
      <textarea id="txtClue1" </textarea>
   </td>
   <td align="center" style="width:150px">
      <span id="spanLinkToPhoto1">
      <button type="button">Link To Photo</button>
      <br>(optional)
      </span>
      <span id="spanPhotoURL1"></span>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="templateRow4_1">
   <td colspan="2">
    <span id="tdCoordinates1">Click here.</span>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="templateRow5_1">
   <td colspan="2">
      <input type="hidden" id="hidLat1">
   </td>
</tr>
```

Please note that when I append this to my table, jquery tries to insert `<tbody>` tags before and after, which messes up the rendering, so I strip that out.

Comment: Note that you're hiding/fading in the `tr` element, not the `templateContents`. Animations on `tr` are *very* flaky. It would probably be best to wrap `templateContents` in a `div` and animate that instead.

Comment: Exactly, your `fadeIn()` will animate your `tr:last` not your `templateContents` that you just added.

Comment: Now that you've added your `templateContents` HTML to the question I can see that my first suggestion won't work. With a structure that complex it's going to be very difficult to fade the whole lot in whilst keeping the columns in line with the parent table. If you really want the fadeIn effect I would suggest you rebuild the whole table using a `div` layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden `div` container for your `templateContents`, add them to your `tr` and then call `fadeIn`, on the hidden div container like this

I'd say you should follow Rory's advice, but if still want to continue with existing structure, add `display:none;` inline style to all your `tr`s(of course its a bit cumbersome), select all hidden elements and then show them.

```
var $parent = $('#tblClues');
$parent.find('tr:last').after(templateContents);
$parent.find('tr:hidden').fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: Arkantos, this works good, except that it leaves a noticeable gap on the right side of the TR contents, between the TR and the DIV. How can I make the TR contents completely fill the available div space?

Comment: Don't forget that appending a `div` directly to a table is invalid and will lead to rendering issues, like the gap @SweatCoder mentioned. I did the same and had to edit my answer :D

Comment: what exactly do you have in `templateContents` ? is it a `tr` ? It would help if you can post some sample value of `templateContents`.

Comment: templateContents added.

Comment: Arkantos, your solution works perfectly. I, too, agree that Rory's suggestion of replacing the table with divs would have been the most elegant, but it's a lot more work at this point. Thanks for sticking with this.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Don't forget Rory's advice when you're structuring elements in a table next time.